# Visual Studio sign-in in to my Azure subscription using Godaddy's email address

Tags: azure, visual-studio, subscription, godaddy-api, azure-subscription

I am stuck at Visual Studio sign-in in to my Azure subscription using Godaddy's email address. I receive the below script error. When I signed up for my Azure sponsorship subscription I used my Godaddy's office 365 email and password. Any ideas or suggestions? Everything works fine in the browser but not in Visual studio.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Resolution for me was to open Internet explorer (yes, old IE) settings and delete all cookies, history, etc.  Then re-launch visual studio and the login screen should now give you the option to choose Work/School or Personal after entering your microsoft login (email address), choose the the option that is your Microsoft/VS account, not your godaddy/email account.  For instance: in my case, my domain email is hosted by godaddy but I also have a microsoft account (Personal login option) with the same login (email address).

Comment: Hi, How did you? IOm on windows 11 and I dont have any way to open IE or its settings